# Application submission requirement for Apple Appstore

Tags: iphone, ios

We are planning to submit our iPhone app for certification, but a friend of my suggested that if the application needs the user to login every-time to use the features, then the people at Apple would not certify the application. Can some one please guide me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My app was rejected for `requiring a registration by the user before using any features` once. I asked for a clarification on the same from the App Review team, stating that my app was based on user data, and cannot proceed without authentication. Also, I updated my review Notes in the itunesConnect to mention the same. And it was accepted. :)

For safe side, You can mention this in the review notes and do not forget to give them a sample username and password!
Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

Its not true, you just need to provide a working username and password during the app submission so that apple can test the features.

Answer (score 2):

You are definitely allowed to require a login for the app to function (I've submitted an app with multiple updates that presents a login screen as the initial dialog and locks the rest of the app until the user logs in).

You need to ensure you create a test account for the reviewer to log in with though, so make sure you provide them with a valid test Username/Password combo when you submit the app for review.

Answer (score 2):

While submitting to appstore there will be option for demo account like Username/password credentials there you can give your credentials to test your application

Comment: Its k friend all the best @MistryHardik

Answer (score 1):

Dontwory Your app will not be rejected by Apple. There is no restriction in apple guidelines for this. I have many live apps in app store with same scenario. So you can upload your app with worrying about app rejection.

Hope it helps you.